# If $a\mid b$ iff $b = ak$, then if $a \nmid b$ could you also say that $b \ne ak$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I am wondering if it's correct to say that if $x \nmid y$ then $y \ne xk$. In this scenario $x$ and $y$ are integers. I know that if $x \nmid y$ you're basically saying that there is no way that $x$ can be multiplied by another integer to equal $y$ and there be no remainder. Would this be the correct way to express that?

Comment: I suggest making the title a bit more clear

Comment: There is only one correct way to express mathematical sentences, and it is *with quantifiers*. Once you have done that for the case at hand, you'll see the semantical shortcomings of your current considerations.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: "you're basically saying that there is no way that $x$ can be multiplied by another integer to equal $y$ $\require{cancel}$  $\cancel{\text{ and there be no remainder}}$".  You do not need to talk of remainders when you are *multiplying* numbers.  But otherwise, that is exactly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

$x \nmid y$ means that there are prime factors (along with their multiplicity) in $x$ that don't exist in $y$. So no matter what you multiply with $x$, it will not create those prime factors in $y$.

The logical proposition would be something equivalent to this:
$$
\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \;\;\; \Bigl [x \nmid y \iff \lnot\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} : y=kx \Bigr]
$$

Comment: `$\nmid$` produces $\nmid$

Answer (score 0):

When you introduce $k$ out of no-where you need to introduce it.

To say quote "$a|b$ iff $b=ka$" unquote, is meaningless nonsense as we have never claimed what $k$ is and $k$ can be anything.  For example, $3|12$ but $12 \ne 3\cdot 516$.  What you *meant* to say, and the correct thing to say is $a|b$ iff *there exist an integer* $k$ so that $a=bk$.  In that way $3|12$ and there exists an integer $k$ so that $12 = 3k$.  That integer happens to be $4$ and does not seem to have anything to do with $516$ or any other integer..

.......

Okay.... that was a little pet peeve of mine.

Now to your question.

.....

The definintion of $a|b$ means that there exists an integer $k$ so that $b=ak$.

So if $a\not \mid b$ that there does not exist *any* integer $k$ so that $b = ak$.  And if there doesn't equal any integer $k$ so $b=ak$ that means for any integer at all, if we label that integer as $k$ then $b\ne ak$.

So we can say if $a\not \mid b$ then for any integer $k$ we have $b\ne ak$.  For instance, $3\not \mid 13$ so $13 \ne 3k$ for any integer $k$.  If $k=4$ then $13 \ne 3\cdot 4$.  If $k =5$ then $13 \ne 3\cdot 5$.  If $k = 516$ then $13 \ne 3\cdot 516$.

Because if there *were* an integer $k$ so that $13=3k$ then.... well, that *is* the definition $3|13$.

And if we know that for $a,b$ that there can not be any integer $k$ so that $b=ak$ then $a\not \mid b$.  Because if $a\mid b$ then we'd know there *was* such an integer.

So....

yes.

$a\not \mid b \iff$ for any integer $k, b \ne ak$.

========

By the way notice if you have and  $A \iff B$ statement.  You *always* have a $A$ is not true $\iff B$ is not true statement.

Because if $A$ not true, then if $B$ were true we'd have $A$ is true (because $A\iff B$).  But $A$ is *not* true (because we were told that) so $B$ is not true.  So $A$ is not true $\implies B$ is not true.

And if $B$ is not true, the we can not have $A$ being true (because that would imply by $A\iff B$ that $B$ *is* true) so $A$ is not true.  So $B$ is not true $\implies A$ is not true.

So  $A$ is not true $\iff B$ is not true.

....

And $A \iff B$ implies the *exact* same thing as: not $A \iff $ not $B$